# client context not initialized error

Tags: javascript, custom-list, client-object-model

I have a client context not initialized error and I have no clue how to fix it I feel like I have tried everything. Would appreciate some help
Here is my code :

Code that gets the list:

```
var SFW = window.SFW || {};
var NBSFeedbackEditInbox = SFW.NBSFeedbackEditInbox || {};

NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackDetails = (function () {

    editdeleted = function (getid, edititem, deleterecordtext, deleterecordid) {
        NBSFeedbackEditInbox.siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/Community/News-and-feedback/Feedback';
        var cContext = new SP.ClientContext(NBSFeedbackEditInbox.siteURL);
        var oList = cContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Feedback Items');

        getid = getid.substring(getid.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
        getid = Math.round(getid);

        oListItem = oList.getItemById(getid);
        if (edititem == 'feedback') {

            oListItem.set_item('RequireFeedback', false);
        }
        if (edititem == 'delete') {


            if (deleterecordtext == 'Sent' || deleterecordtext == 'Inbox') {

                oListItem.set_item('IsDeleted', 'Both');
            }

            if (deleterecordid == 'sentfordelete' && deleterecordtext == 'No') {

                oListItem.set_item('IsDeleted', 'Sent');
            }
            if (deleterecordid == 'inboxfordelete' && deleterecordtext == 'No') {

                oListItem.set_item('IsDeleted', 'Inbox');
            }
        }
        oListItem.update();

        cContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

    }
    onQuerySucceeded = function () {


    }

    onQueryFailed = function (sender, args) {


    }

    return {
        editdeleted: editdeleted
    }

})()

NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackRemove = (function () {
    var listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback,
    collListItems;
    var cContext;
    removemessage = function (getid) {

        NBSFeedbackEditInbox.siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/Community/News-and-feedback/Feedback';
        cContext = new SP.ClientContext(NBSFeedbackEditInbox.siteURL);
        var oList = cContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Feedback Items');

        var querystring = jQuery('#createdby').text();

        for (var i = 0; i < getid.length; i++) {


            getid[i] = getid[i].substring(getid[i].lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
            getid[i] = Math.round(getid[i]);

        }

        if (getid.length != 0) {
            var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
            query.set_viewXml("<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='Text'>" + querystring + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>");
            collListItems = oList.getItems(query);


            cContext.load(collListItems, 'Include(Title, ID,IsDeleted,RequireFeedback)');

            cContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
        }

    }
    onQuerySucceeded = function () {
        var itemTitle = [];
        var sentnumber = 0;
        var inboxnumber = 0;
        listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback = collListItems.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback.moveNext()) {

            feedbackListItem = listItemEnumeratorlistFeedback.get_current();

            if (feedbackListItem.get_item('IsDeleted') == 'Sent' || feedbackListItem.get_item('RequireFeedback') == false || feedbackListItem.get_item('IsDeleted') == 'Both') {
                jQuery("div[title='" + (feedbackListItem.get_item('Title')) + "sent']").parent().parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');

                var sentlength = jQuery('.nbsallmessagecountsent').filter(function () { return $(this).css("display") != "none" }).length;


                jQuery("#nbsmessagesentcount").text('Showing ' + sentlength + ' of ' + sentlength + ' conversations');
                if (sentlength <= 0) {
                    jQuery('#sentcounters').addClass('nbsmessageremoval');
                } else {
                    jQuery('#sentcounters').removeClass('nbsmessageremoval');
                }



            }

            if (feedbackListItem.get_item('IsDeleted') == 'Inbox' || feedbackListItem.get_item('IsDeleted') == 'Both') {

                jQuery("div[title='" + (feedbackListItem.get_item('Title')) + "inbox']").parent().parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
                var inboxlength = jQuery('.allmessagecount').filter(function () { return $(this).css("display") != "none" }).length;
                jQuery("#nbsmessageinboxcount").text('Showing ' + inboxlength + ' of ' + inboxlength + ' conversations');

                if (inboxlength == 0) {
                    jQuery('#nbsnewmessages').text('');
                } else {
                    jQuery('#nbsnewmessages').text('(' + inboxlength + ')');
                }
                if (inboxlength <= 0) {
                    jQuery('#nbsdeletemessage').addClass('nbsmessageremoval');
                } else {
                    jQuery('#nbsdeletemessage').removeClass('nbsmessageremoval');
                }

            }
        }

    }

    onQueryFailed = function (sender, args) {

    }

    return {
        removemessage: removemessage
    }

})()
```

Code that calls the method:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {



        if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
            Array.prototype.indexOf = function (elt /*, from*/) {
                var len = this.length >>> 0;

                var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
                from = (from < 0)
                     ? Math.ceil(from)
                     : Math.floor(from);
                if (from < 0)
                    from += len;

                for (; from < len; from++) {
                    if (from in this &&
                        this[from] === elt)
                        return from;
                }
                return -1;
            };
        }
        var itemid = [];
        jQuery("div#NBSinboxsent").find(".itemid").each(function () {
            itemid.push(jQuery(this).text());
        });

        var inboxid = [];
        jQuery("div#NBSinboxsent").find(".inboxid").each(function () {
            inboxid.push(jQuery(this).text());
        });
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(someSimpleWrapper, "sp.js");

function someSimpleWrapper(){

  NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackRemove.removemessage(itemid);



  NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackRemove.removemessage(inboxid);

}

        var countinbox = 0;
        var count = 0;
        var checkedidfeedback = [];
        var checkedidsentdelete = [];
        var checkedidinboxdelete = [];

        var sentlength = jQuery('.nbsforthechopsent').filter(function () { return $(this).css("display") != "none" }).length;
        var inboxlength = jQuery('.nbsforthechop').filter(function () { return $(this).css("display") != "none" }).length;
        var nbsconversationbetween = jQuery('#conversationbetweenreply').text();
        nbsconversationbetween = nbsconversationbetween.replace(';', ' and ');

        jQuery('#nbsnameofuser').html('<h2 style="padding-bottom:15px;">' + jQuery('.CreatedByreply').attr('title') + '</h2>');
        jQuery("#nbsmessageinboxcount").text('Showing ' + inboxlength + ' of ' + inboxlength + ' conversations');
        jQuery("#nbsmessagesentcount").text('Showing ' + sentlength + ' of ' + sentlength + ' conversations');
        if (jQuery('.nbs-newmessage').length > 0) {
            jQuery('#nbsnewmessages').text(' (' + jQuery('.nbs-newmessage').length + ')');
        }
        if (inboxlength <= 0) {
            jQuery('#nbsdeletemessage').addClass('nbsmessageremoval');
        } else {
            jQuery('#nbsdeletemessage').removeClass('nbsmessageremoval');
        }
        if (sentlength <= 0) {
            jQuery('#sentcounters').addClass('nbsmessageremoval');
        } else {
            jQuery('#sentcounters').removeClass('nbsmessageremoval');
        }



        //withdraw single feedback
        jQuery('.removefeedback').click(function () {
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
            var deletecheck = jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            deletecheck = deletecheck + 'checkbox';
            jQuery('#' + deletecheck).css('display', 'none');

            var getid = jQuery(this).parent().last().text();

            NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackDetails.editdeleted(getid, 'feedback', null, null);

            if (count > 0) {
                count = count - 1;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
            if (sentlength <= 0) {
                jQuery('#sentcounters').addClass('nbsmessageremoval');
            }
            if (count <= 0) {
                jQuery('.nbsdeletecountsent').text('');

            } else {
                jQuery('.nbsdeletecountsent').text('(' + count + ')');
            }
        });

        //count inbox checkbox
        jQuery('.nbsforthechop').change(function () {

            var deleteid = jQuery(this).attr('id');

            deleteid = deleteid.replace('checkbox', '');

            if (jQuery(this).is(':checked') == true) {
                checkedidinboxdelete.push(deleteid);
                jQuery('#' + deleteid).addClass('coloronchecked');
                countinbox++;
            } else {
                var i = checkedidinboxdelete.indexOf(deleteid);
                if (i != -1) {
                    checkedidinboxdelete.splice(i, 1);
                }

                jQuery('#' + deleteid).removeClass('coloronchecked');
                countinbox = countinbox - 1;

            }
            if (countinbox <= 0) {
                jQuery('#nbsdeletecount').text('');

            } else {
                jQuery('#nbsdeletecount').text('(' + countinbox + ')');
            }

        });

        //count sent checkbox
        jQuery('.nbsforthechopsent').change(function () {
            var deleteid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            deleteid = deleteid.replace('checkbox', '');

            if (jQuery(this).is(':checked') == true) {
                jQuery('#' + deleteid).addClass('coloronchecked');
                checkedidfeedback.push(deleteid);
                checkedidsentdelete.push(deleteid);
                count++;
            } else {
                var i = checkedidsentdelete.indexOf(deleteid);
                if (i != -1) {
                    checkedidsentdelete.splice(i, 1);
                }
                var i = checkedidfeedback.indexOf(deleteid);
                if (i != -1) {
                    checkedidfeedback.splice(i, 1);
                }

                jQuery('#' + deleteid).removeClass('coloronchecked');
                count = count - 1;

            }
            if (count <= 0) {
                jQuery('.nbsdeletecountsent').text('');

            } else {
                jQuery('.nbsdeletecountsent').text('(' + count + ')');
            }
        });

        //checkbox withdraw feedback
        jQuery('.withdrawfeedback').click(function () {
            if (checkedidfeedback.length != 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < checkedidfeedback.length; i++) {
                    jQuery('#' + checkedidfeedback[i]).css('display', 'none');
                    jQuery('#' + checkedidfeedback[i]).parent().css('display', 'none');
                    deleteid = checkedidfeedback[i] + 'checkbox';
                    jQuery('#' + deleteid).css('display', 'none');
                    var getid = (jQuery('#' + checkedidfeedback[i] + ' div').last().text());
                    NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackDetails.editdeleted(getid, 'feedback', null, null);

                }
                count = 0;
                jQuery('.nbsdeletecountsent').text('');
                jQuery("#nbsmessagesentcount").text('Showing ' + sentlength + ' of ' + sentlength + ' conversations');
            }
            checkedidfeedback = [];
            checkedidsentdelete = [];
        });

        //checkbox delete inbox message
        jQuery('.deleteinbox').click(function () {
            if (checkedidinboxdelete.length != 0) {

                for (var i = 0; i < checkedidinboxdelete.length; i++) {
                    jQuery('#' + checkedidinboxdelete[i]).css('display', 'none');
                    jQuery('#' + checkedidinboxdelete[i]).parent().css('display', 'none');

                    deleteid = checkedidinboxdelete[i] + 'checkbox';
                    jQuery('#' + deleteid).css('display', 'none');
                    var getid = (jQuery('#' + checkedidinboxdelete[i] + ' div').last().text());

                    var deleterecordtext = (jQuery('#' + checkedidinboxdelete[i] + ' small').last().text());
                    var deleterecordid = (jQuery('#' + checkedidinboxdelete[i] + ' small').last().attr('id'));

                    NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackDetails.editdeleted(getid, 'delete', deleterecordtext, deleterecordid);
                    NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackRemove.removemessage;
                }
                countinbox = 0;

                jQuery('#nbsdeletecount').text('');

            }
            checkedidinboxdelete = [];
        });

        //checkbox delete sent message
        jQuery('.deletesent').click(function () {

            if (checkedidsentdelete.length != 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < checkedidsentdelete.length; i++) {
                    jQuery('#' + checkedidsentdelete[i]).css('display', 'none');
                    jQuery('#' + checkedidfeedback[i]).parent().css('display', 'none');

                    deleteid = checkedidsentdelete[i] + 'checkbox';
                    jQuery('#' + deleteid).css('display', 'none');
                    var getid = (jQuery('#' + checkedidfeedback[i] + ' div').last().text());

                    var deleterecordtext = (jQuery('#' + checkedidfeedback[i] + ' small').last().text());
                    var deleterecordid = (jQuery('#' + checkedidfeedback[i] + ' small').last().attr('id'));


                    NBSFeedbackEditInbox.FeedbackDetails.editdeleted(getid, 'delete', deleterecordtext, deleterecordid);

                }
                count = 0;
                jQuery('.nbsdeletecountsent').text('');
            }
            checkedidsentdelete = [];
            checkedidfeedback = [];
        });




});
```

I don't know what else to try, it's getting really frustrating now

Comment: Try `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded("sp.js",someSimpleWrapper );`

Comment: Did you include <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script> ?

Comment: I get in init.js Object doesn't support property tolowercase for SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded("sp.js",someSimpleWrapper );

Comment: I have not touched init.js either

Comment: had to add SP.ClientContext to it too Amal was correct, can put as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the function as follows

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded("sp.js","sp.ClientContext.js",someSimpleWrapper );
```

Comment: I now get Unable to get property 'getEnumerator' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the below code:

**Function Definition something as below:**

```
function functionName()
{
      try {
          var ListName = "Demo";
          var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); // the current context is taken by default here
            //you can also create a particular site context as follows
            //var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteURL);
            var lstObject = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
            this.lstObjectItem = lstObject.getItemById(ID);
            lstObjectItem.deleteObject();
            }

            catch(exception){var message = exception.message;alert('Exception:'+message);}
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailure));
        }
}
```

**Try calling your function using below code:**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', null, function(){
      functionName()
    })
```

Comment: I now get Unable to get property 'getEnumerator' of undefined or null reference